# Java vararg vs collection overloading

Tags: java, operator-overloading, overloading

Consider the following code:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    public static void print(Collection<Object> strings) {
        System.out.println("Collection overload: " + strings);
    }

    public static void print(Object... strings) {
        System.out.println("Vararg overload: " + Arrays.asList(strings));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
        print(strings);
    }
}
```

What's your prediction of the output?

It turns out, the correct answer is this!

```
Vararg overload: [[hello, world]]
```

If you guessed right, could you please explain why it's not the collection overload?

**Update**

If I change the collection overload to

```
   public static void print(Collection<String> strings) {
      System.out.println("Collection overload: " + strings);
   }
```

or

```
   public static void print(Collection strings) {
      System.out.println("Collection overload: " + strings);
   }
```

Then it outputs

```
Collection overload: [hello, world]
```

Comment: See also [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for the last snippet in your update.

Comment: Not an answer, but for your entertainment, [the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) "Generally speaking, you should not overload a varargs method, or it will be difficult for programmers to figure out which overloading gets called."